# Remember sudo password in Xbian

Tags: sudo, xbian

How can I make Xbian to remember the sudo password for a while? Performing administration tasks on it gets painful with the OS requesting sudo password at every command.

The funny thing is that if you go editing `visudo` you can see that you have:

```
Defaults:xbian timestamp_timeout=20
```

(note: I'm actually using `xbian` user)

How to make it remember?

PS: I know about `sudo su`. But is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

The default password timeout is 15 minutes. So if you use sudo twice in 15 minutes (900 seconds), you will not be asked to type the user’s password again.

The **`timestamp_timeout`**:

The `timestamp_timeout` defines the number of minutes that can elapse before `sudo` will ask for a password again. To modify the timestamp_timeout, edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I recommend you to use `visudo`, when editing the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Append the `timestamp_timeout` value to the `Defaults` line, in `/etc/sudoers`.

Make the `Defaults` line to look like this:

```
Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=10
```

`timestamp_timeout=0` (zero) makes the sudo password expire every 0 (zero) seconds. This means that every time you use sudo, you will be asked for the password.

`timestamp_timeout=-1` (minus one) makes the sudo password not expire.

from: [Change Sudo Password Timeout](http://linuxg.net/change-sudo-password-timeout/)

Comment: As I said. I DO use visudo. I DO have this timestap_timeout in my sudoers, and I DO get asked for the password every single time. Please read the question

Comment: @javirs Did you try out timestamp_timeout=-1?